# Transfer data from U-SQL managed table to Azure SQL Database table

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I have a U-SQL managed table that contains schematized structured data.

```
CREATE TABLE [AdlaDb].[dbo].[User]
(
    UserGuid Guid,
    Postcode string,
    Age int?
    DateOfBirth DateTime?,
)
```

And a Azure SQL Database table.

```
CREATE TABLE [SqlDb].[dbo].[User]
(
    UserGuid    uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
    Postcode    varchar(15) NULL,
    Age         int NULL,
    DateOfBirth Date NULL,
)
```

I would like to transfer data from U-SQL managed table to Azure SQLDB table without losing the data types.

I'm using azure data factory, seems like I cannot

1. directly query the U-SQL managed table as an input dataset for data factory
2. do a federated **write** query to Azure SQLDB

Hence I'm having an intermediate step where I copy from U-SQL managed table to Azure Blob and then move to Azure SQLDB table. Doing this, I'm losing the data type and having to have type conversion/transformations later again before inserting.

Is there any better way to transfer data from U-SQL managed table to Azure SQL Database table without losing data type? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

At this point you have the following option:

1. Export the U-SQL table into an intermediate format (e.g., CSV) in ADLS or blob storage.
2. Use ADF to move the file into Azure SQL DB.

I know that the ADF team has a work item to do this for you. I will ask them to reply to this thread as well.

Directly writing into a table from a U-SQL script has a lot of challenges due to the fault-tolerant retry and scale-out processing in U-SQL. This makes atomic writing in parallel into a transacted store a bit more complex (see for example http://www.vldb.org/conf/1996/P460.PDF).

Comment: Has being able to pull data from U-SQL managed tables from Data Factory been implemented yet?  I would like to iterate over the rows in a U-SQL table but cannot seem to do this without first exporting to a CSV.

Answer (score 2):

There is now another option to transfer data from USQL managed table to Azure SQL Database table.

- Write out the data from USQL Managed table or from a USQL script to Azure Blob Storage as a text file (.csv, .txt etc..)
- And then make use of the public preview [feature](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/updates/preview-loading-files-from-azure-blob-storage-into-sql-database/) in Azure SQL Database - BULK INSERT - wrap this into a stored procedure
- Add an Stored procedure activity in Azure Data Factory to schedule

Note: There is one thing to be aware of when creating DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL, refer this Stack Overflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42793902/loading-file-from-azure-blob-storage-into-azure-sql-database-using-bulk-insert)