# Is it possible to use U-SQL managed tables as output datasets in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I have a small ADF pipeline that copies a series of files from an Azure Storage Account to an Azure Data Lake account. As a final activity in the pipeline I want to run a U-SQL script that uses the copied files as inputs and outputs the result to a U-SQL managed table.

The U-SQL script basically extracts the data from the copied files, applies some transformation and then INSERT´s it into an existing U-SQL managed table.

How (if possible) can I add the U-SQL table as a output dataset in Azure Data Factory?

Comment: I am wondering why you are using ADF for copying data. You can directly read data from Azure blob, process it and directly write it in managed table using U-SQL.

Comment: Yes that could be done but in this case only a subset of the data from the copied files are added to the table. But I still need to persist the complete JSON file in the DataLake. We only persist the files for 30 days in the storage account. Either way the question still applies.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot currently add a U-SQL internal table as an output dataset in Azure Data Factory (ADF).  A similar question came up recently [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40894131/transfer-data-from-u-sql-managed-table-to-azure-sql-database-table) and the answer from Michael Rys (the "father" of U-SQL) was "I know that the ADF team has a work item to do this for you."

You could use howerver Azure Data Factory to run a *parameterised* U-SQL script, where the input parameter is the filepath.  This would have a similar result.

Example pipeline from a [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41443467/error-while-running-u-sql-activity-in-pipeline-in-azure-data-factory):

```
{
    "name": "ComputeEventsByRegionPipeline",
    "properties": {
        "description": "This is a pipeline to compute events for en-gb locale and date less than 2012/02/19.",
        "activities": [
            {
                "type": "DataLakeAnalyticsU-SQL",
                "typeProperties": {
                    "scriptPath": "adlascripts\\SearchLogProcessing.txt",
                    "scriptLinkedService": "StorageLinkedService",
                    "degreeOfParallelism": 3,
                    "priority": 100,
                    "parameters": {
                        "in": "/input/SearchLog.tsv",
                        "out": "/output/Result.tsv"
                    }
                },
...
```

Basically the U-SQL script goes from:

```
@searchlog =
    EXTRACT ...
    FROM @in
    USING Extractors.Tsv();
```

to:

```
@searchlog =
    EXTRACT ...
    FROM "/input/SearchLog.tsv"
    USING Extractors.Tsv();
```

which I think achieves the same thing you want.

Comment: I had already implemented the dynamic parameters but after reading your answer I just added an OUTPUT of a CSV file to the Data Lake Store with one row and column in the end of the U-SQL script. This solved the problem.

Comment: Great!  Would you consider marking that as the answer, or do you think it's not really an answer to the question?

Comment: It answers the question partly but not the critical part on how to work around the fact that you need to supply ADF with a proper output dataset.